# Can Apache Configuration File (httpd.conf) Be Located Elsewhere?

Tags: windows, apache, configuration-files, httpd.conf

I have been using Apache on Windows (+PHP +MySQL) for a long time now. Lately, I decided to have the configuration files of Apache, PHP and MySQL in one directory, outside of the installation folders of any of them.

With PHP it works by setting `PHPIniDir` in Apache's `httpd.conf`

With MySQL it works by setting the `--defaults-file=<path/to/my.ini>` option while installing on the command line as a Windows service.

With Apache itself, I haven't been able to find a way. Is it possible to choose an arbitrary location or name for the `httpd.conf` file? And how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use "..-f httpd.conf" on startup. see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/de/invoking.html

Regards

Comment: Thank you @srIT for your very useful link to the manual. Funny I hadn't been "very close" to Apache Manual! For the sake of others, the full solution was to do: `httpd.exe -k install -f "path\to\httpd.conf"` in order to install Apache as a Windows service. Optionally, add `-n "NameOfService"`, or else Apache will use "Apache2.4" (currently) as the service name.